# cake php captcha problem

Tags: cakephp, captcha

I am facing problem with captcha in cake php. when try to call captcha the session value display previous one. so never get the right answer.

Here is my code.

For component section i put this code

```
class CaptchaComponent extends Object
{
    var $controller; 

 var $font = 'monofont.ttf';

 function CaptchaComponent( $controller ) {
  $this->controller = $controller;
 }

 function generateCode($characters) {
  /* list all possible characters, similar looking characters and vowels have been removed */
  $possible = '23456789bcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyz';
  $code = '';
  $i = 0;
  while ($i < $characters) { 
   $code .= substr($possible, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible)-1), 1);
   $i++;
  }
  return $code;
 }

 function create($width='120',$height='40',$characters='6') {
  $code = $this->generateCode($characters);
  /* font size will be 75% of the image height */
  $font_size = $height * 0.80;
  $image = @imagecreate($width, $height) or die('Cannot initialize new GD image stream');
  /* set the colours */
  $background_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 220, 220, 220);
  $text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 10, 30, 80);
  $noise_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 150, 180, 220);
  /* generate random dots in background */
  for( $i=0; $i<($width*$height)/3; $i++ ) {
   imagefilledellipse($image, mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), 1, 1, $noise_color);
  }
  /* generate random lines in background */
  for( $i=0; $i<($width*$height)/150; $i++ ) {
   imageline($image, mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), $noise_color);
  }
  /* create textbox and add text */
  $textbox = imagettfbbox($font_size, 0, $this->font, $code) or die('Error in imagettfbbox function');
  $x = ($width - $textbox[4])/2;
  $y = ($height - $textbox[5])/2;
  imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, $x, $y, $text_color, $this->font , $code) or die('Error in imagettftext function');
  /* output captcha image to browser */
  header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
  imagejpeg($image);
  imagedestroy($image);
  $this->controller->Session->write('security_code',$code);
 }
}
```

For user controller section my code is

```
function captcha() {

   App::import('Component','Captcha');
  $this->Captcha = new CaptchaComponent($this);
   $this->Captcha->create();

 }
```

and for view option my code is

```
echo $html->image('../users/captcha',  
 array('style'=>'border:1px #ccc solid','vspace'=>2)  
 );
```

Comment: Make sure you aren't redirecting again before it checks. Also you might want to do the check in specific code before you save.

Comment: Thanks DavidYell,                                                   My problem is solved with create text with session and then create the captcha code for that perticular text.

Answer (score 0):

Latest working version of this captcha component for CakePHP 2.x is available at author's website here http://www.devarticles.in/cakephp/simple-captcha-component-for-cakephp/